# jQuery: Scroll down and scroll up with slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below slides down and up four elements of the list. These elements, of course has its height. So the question is: how to slide down or up elements and at the same time slide page scroll?

Thank You.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $(".partners__ul li");
  var numToShow = 4;
  var button = $(".partners__button__a");
  var numInList = list.length;
  var isShowing = true;
  list.hide();
  if (numInList > numToShow) {
    button.show();
  }
  list.slice(0, numToShow).show();
  button.click(function() {
    var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
    if (isShowing) {
      list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn(100, onFadeComplete);
    } else {
      list.slice(showing - numToShow, numInList).fadeOut(100, onFadeComplete);
    }


  });

  function onFadeComplete() {
    var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;

    if (nowShowing == numInList && isShowing) {
      isShowing = false;
      button.text("Show less");
    } else if (isShowing) {
      button.text("Show even more");
    }

    if (nowShowing == numToShow) {
      button.text("Show more");
      isShowing = true;
    }

  }
});
```

```css
.partners__ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.partners__ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="partners__ul">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="partners__button__a">Show More</button>
  <button class="partners__button__a_less" style="display:none">Show Less</button>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried .`stop()` method?

Answer (score 1):

I often do something like the code below to get the slide animation:

```
$(".scrollto").click(function(e) { 
       var btn = $(e.currentTarget);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(btn.attr("href")).offset().top 
        }, 1000);
    });
```

I use the code above to implement animations(slide effect) to my header website. You can use it for your own. Also if you want you can add your html code and I can update the answer.

I hope it's helps.

EDITED:

Basically I have added a piece of code in your function `onFadeComplete()` as you can see below: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zz7pvway/1/)

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.partners__ul li').last().offset().top }, 1000);
```

I have set the scroll to the body so in the example is not working but in your website should work fine.

Comment: Thank You! I've updated the question and add html and css.